# Type Any has no subscript members (Array, Swift 3.0)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, swift3

2 Years ago I developed an iOS app and now I need to update it. I just converted my Swift project to 3.0 and I'm using XCode8. I already solved almost every issues but I can't solve this one even after searching on already opened almost every question concerning this error "Type Any has no subscript members"

Thank you for helping me

[image]

Comment: A simple search with your error message brings 64 results: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5DType+Any+has+no+subscript+members Are really none of those helpful for you? It's hard to believe. ;) Please explain how it didn't work for you, what you tried, etc. Thanks.

Comment: add here "arrayPrefs"  declaration code

Comment: @EricAya  thank you for your useless comment. As I wrote I already tried almost every result I can find in stackoverflow. Always same error or worst as add a ";" with no sense after the bracket.

Comment: His comment not useless. Useless is your question, because there is no way to understand it, to understand what types you are using and what do you what from your code. Also this is so bad style, posting code by screenshots.

Comment: @ShadowOf I really don't understand your point. Code is clear enough. In a variable called "prefToLoad" is loaded the URL stored into the defaults. Come on guys, stop raging on me and.. if you are not able to answering this just don't do it only to receive a "+" on your usefull answers.. thanks.

Comment: If you look at the similar questions then you'll notice that the problem is *always the same:* You have a variable of type `Any` and want it to be treated as an array (or dictionary, array of dictionaries, or dictionary of arrays, or ...). So you have to *cast* it: `arrayPrefs as? SomeThing` and figure out what SomeThing is. If you don't manage that for  the entire expression, start with a simpler expression: `let foo = arrayPrefs[indexPath.row]` and make that compile by casting `arrayPrefs` to ... (an array perhaps?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Issue

The problem that you're having is that you're trying to access a `subscript` (current case is trying to get a value by a string key) where your object is of type `Any`.

### Solution

**arrayPrefs** is a `NSArray` which is bridged into Swift as `[Any]`. Since this is an array you're getting the value **arrayPrefs[index]** and we're good so far. Now since the **Type** of the element inside the array is `Any` accessing it by key doesn't work, as `Any` doesn't have a subscript. In order to access the subscript, first you need to check if the element (`Any`) can be typecasted to a `Dictionary<String, Any>` (`[String: Any]`).

To achieve it, change

`prefToLoad = arrayPrefs[indexPath.row]["url"] as! String`

with

```
if let pref = arrayPrefs[indexPath.row] as? [String: Any] {
    prefToLoad = pref["url"] as! String
    
    // The rest of your code
}
```

Comment: thank you for the explication and the possible solution. It looks like it is working! But I'm having trouble replicating this on the other method regarding the cell (cell.textLabel?.text = arrayPrefs[indexPath.row]["name"] as? String)... how should I replace this other row? Thank you very much

Comment: `let pref = arrayPrefs[indexPath.row] as! [String: Any]`

`cell.textLabel?.text = pref["name"] as? String`

Comment: Great, that's perfect!